# Capturing and filtering all logs locally in terminal

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have a service that typically runs in a hosted production environment, spitting out logs and whatnot.

I've written a script to test different pieces of the service locally, and i want to capture all the logs being output by the different libraries and files, and only print out the relevant logs to my terminal console.

I can't seem to figure out how to make use of the `logger.addFilter` or `addHandler` methods, and im not really sure how to make use of the StreamHandler either.

I've noticed that when i pass an instantiated StreamHandler to my root_logger handlers, it removes all top level logs, but doesn't capture loggers with nested names still.

ex.

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
root_logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

...

run_script()

> {'name': 'service.library.loggerA'} < still logged
> {'name': 'service.library.loggerB'} < still logged
> {'name': 'ServiceClass'} < NOT logged
```

Would anyone be able to help me underestand what all these pieces do and how i can use them to filter out all logs in my tool?

Comment: Are we talking about a unit test that actually runs the code, or a client test which interacts with a separate server? If you're running the code inside a test you can configure the logging. Othewise you can only tail the log and filter out the ones you want.

Comment: Not inside a unit test unfortunately :(

from my understanding there's ways to filter logs via logging.AddFilter however filters are not propogated to child loggers.
Handlers may be propogated though.

I suppose now i'm confused as to how to find all the children loggers of the root...